# Cómo mostrar con SQL los registros de una tabla que cumplan con el criterio de una suma

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta tabla con el campo `cargas`:

```
Create table 'ctos_cargas' (
    'Interruptor' varchar (10) null default null,
    'Municipio' varchar (50) null default null,
    'Subestacion' varchar (50) null default null,
    'Carga' varchar (3) null default null
)
Collate='latin_swedish_ci'
Engine= InnoDB ;
```

Lo que quisiera lograr es que se vayan mostrando registros de forma tal que a medida que se vayan sumando el resultado sea menor que `10`, por ejemplo.

Mi duda es si se puede hacer directamente desde SQL o hay que recurrir a la programación.

Aquí muestro una síntesis de los datos de la tabla:

[image: Foto del contenido de la tabla]

Ahora lo que pretendo es, por ejemplo, que seleccione los registros mientras se cumpla la condición de que la suma de los registros sea igual a 5.

Ejemplo:

En este caso sería `S500`, `S466`, `S467`.

O sea, `2 + 1 + 2 = 5`.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nos vendría saber, al menos, la consulta SQL que obtiene todos los registros para ayudarte con ella, además de ejemplos de datos de entrada y lo que se espera en la salida.

Comment: Oscar ya agregue lo que me pedias, hay un foto de la tabla y te explico brevemente lo que pretendo hacer.

Comment: Averigua sobre over...

Comment: Gbianchi no logro ver lo que me recomienda en su comentario, en over me pone .... y no se que me quiere decir.

Comment: ¿Te fue de ayuda en código SQL que te proporcioné o no es lo que necesitabas? Déjame un comentario en mi respuesta si tienes alguna duda o falta algo en ella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que deseas debes usar una variable en la que acumulas la carga de cada registro de la siguiente manera:

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT
  *, @total := @total + Carga
FROM
  ctos_cargas
WHERE
  @total < 5;
```

Este bucle terminará sumando el último valor, aunque llegue o se pase de `5`, ya que el `WHERE` evaluará el valor de `@total` antes de ser sumada la carga del registro en curso.

Si quieres que esto no ocurra, entonces debes usar lo siguiente:

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT
  *, @total := @total + Carga
FROM
  ctos_cargas
WHERE
  @total + Carga < 5;
```

Ahora estamos agregando la carga del registro en el `WHERE` para que se tome ésta en cuenta.

Puedes comprobar el funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/whjV2NuuYrikmycZV2P6WB/0

Comment: Oscar agradecido, funciona perfecto para mi, verdad que no tuve en cuenta nunca lo del uso de una variable. Perfecta solucion. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si solucionó tu problema no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.