# Consulta mysqli que comienza con set @total no se ejecuta en php

Tags: mysqli, php7, set

En phpstorm programando tengo esta consulta

```
set @total=0; 
Select *, @total:+@total, numeros from Numeros 
where @total + numero < 10
```

Esta consulta lo que hace es ir sumando los numeros mientras el total sea menor que 10. Ahora a la hora de mostrarlo en el navegador me da error de que le falta un parámetro a `mysqli_fetch_array` para
ser un `result`.

Sin embargo en el motor de heidisql todo queda perfecto. No se que pasa.

Comment: Puedes iniciar la variable en una subconsulta: `FROM  Numeros, (SELECT @total := 0) v WHERE`

Comment: En realidad eso no es una consulta, si no que son **dos** consultas, por lo que debes separaras en dos llamadas. En la primera asignas a una [variable definida por el usuario (o también llamadas variables de sesión)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html#set-variable-user-variables) un valor y en la segunda realizas el `SELECT` en sí. Si quieres ejecutar múltiples consultas de una vez debes usar en su lugar [`mysqli_multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/es/mysqli.multi-query).

Comment: Por cierto, te recuerdo que en tu pregunta anterior (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477225/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-con-sql-los-registros-de-una-tabla-que-cumplan-con-el-criterio-de-u) aún estoy esperando que marques mi respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Y como te la marco oscar, es que soy nuevo en esto y las ediciones las hago desde un smartphone. Disculpa y siempre bienvenidas tus respuestas. Gracias.

Comment: Si compartes el código PHP que usas puedo ayudarte a adaptarlo con una u otra solución (dos consultas o una consulta múltiple).

Comment: ¿Solucionaste tú mismo este problema o aún necesitas ayuda?

Comment: Estoy ahi todavia con problemas, es que se rompio la laptop y estoy en otra. No logro dar con el problema, como te decia en heidisql todo marcha bien y tu solucion me funciona, pero a la hora de mostrarlo en php no lo hace. Sin embargo cualquier consulta que no comience con set si la muestra y sale bien en la página. Asi que no se que pasa.