# Consulta mysqli que comienza con set @variable me devuelve 0

Tags: php, mysqli, set

Aquí esta la consulta:

```sql
set @total=0; 
Select *, @total:+@total, numeros from Numeros 
where @total + numero < 10
```

En el motor de bd devuelve todo bien, pero en la web no lo hace. Sin embargo, le quito el set y ejecuto la consulta cambiando la consulta claro y si se muestra todo perfecto en la web. Que puedo hacer?? Gracias.

Comment: No funciona porque en realidad son dos consultas. Entonces, o bien las ejecutas por separado, o usas [`multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: ¿Es la [misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/482693)?

Comment: Sal, es la misma pregunta, pero el tema es que no logro resolver el problema. Cedano, y como seria hacer dos consultas si me hace falta el valor del set para que se ejecute mi consulta?? Algun consejo?? Gracias.

Comment: Pues haciendo algo así más o menos: `$mysqli->query("set @total=0");`  y seguido: `$mysqli->query("Select *, @total:+@total, numeros from Numeros 
where @total + numero < 10");` Y si no con multi_query, en cuyo caso escribirías ambas consultas en una sola sentencia, teniendo cuidado de separar cada consulta por punto y coma: `$mysqli->multi_query("set @total=0; 
Select *, @total:+@total, numeros from Numeros 
where @total + numero < 10");` Sea como sea, debes agregar siempre en la pregunta el código que estés implementando. Si te decides por multi_query revisa lo que dice el Manual.